# File Reader Return Null

Tags: java, file

I have the Java code bellow for reading a csv file , but the output is NULL.
the code read the file and assign it to a double array.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class CSVReader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    try {
      double[][] Data = null;
      Data = CSVReader.read("C:\\Users\\mrezz\\Data.csv", true);
      System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(Data));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static double[][] read(String theFile, boolean hasTitle) throws IOException {
    try {
      boolean firstTime = true;
      double[][] data = null;

      File file = new File(theFile);
      int row = 0;
      int col = 0;

      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
      bufferedReader.close();

      String line;

      if (hasTitle) {
        line = reader.readLine();
      }
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (firstTime) {
          firstTime = false;

          StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
          col = 0;
          while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            st.nextToken();
            col++;
          }
          data = new double[row][col];
          col = 0;
          continue;
        }
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {

          data[row][col] = Double.valueOf(st.nextToken());
          col++;
        }
        col = 0;
        row++;
      }

      return data;

    } catch (Exception e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The code should assign the file to a (double [][] data ) array.

any help please

Comment: An exception indicates that your operation has failed, and it is not appropriate to continue as if the operation succeeded.  Don’t ignore your exception!  Remove the try/catch from your `read` method.  In your `main` method, replace your System.out.println(e.getMessage()) line with `e.printStackTrace();`.  The exception will tell you exactly what went wrong, and where.

Comment: @VGR i have  Arrayindexoutofbound Excption ??

Comment: Look at the stack trace of the exception.  It shows what line of your code caused the exception.  If you edit your question and share that information with us, you are more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You probably get an exception and return `null` without reporting it to the user.

I suspect the last `return null;` in the above code.